# Datatable export buttons are not showing

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatables

and code if datatabble jquery is as:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

    <!-- buttons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.3.1/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" defer></script>
```

and jquery datatable code is as:

```
$('#dataTableInward').DataTable({
                "lengthMenu": [[50, 100, 150, -1], [50, 100, 150, 200, 300, 500, 1000]],
                dom: 'Blfrtip',
                "buttons": [
                    'excel', 'csv', 'print', 'copy'
                ],
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/getDbData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": "json"
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Id" },
                    { "data": "Inward_No" },
                    { "data": "Inward_Date" },
                    { "data": "Claim_Type" },
                    { "data": "Expense_Type" },
                    { "data": "Inwarded_By" },
            ....
```

Please help me in this... everything is working perfect just export buttons are not visible

Answer (score 1):

Please review your library references for the buttons to show up, you will need below references

```
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src ="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>

    $('#grid').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                        'copy',
                        'csv'
            ],
            data: json.result,
            columns: [
                { data: "engine" },
                { data: "browser" },
                { data: "platform" },
                { data: "version" }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixture of different scripts in your header, which need to be cleaned up.

For example, you have:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js (deferred)
```

But you also have:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js
```

Also, when I run your code and open my browser's console (e.g. via F11), I can see the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: i.Buttons is undefined
```

Does the following script exist? And is it in the right location to be accessed by your page?

```
~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.buttons.js
```

You also tagged your question as a `bootstrap-4` question - but I do not see any Bootstrap-related libraries on your page.

**Suggestion:**

Your DataTables code looks OK.  But I would remove all those JS and CSS imports and start again.

Go to the DataTables [download builder](https://datatables.net/download/) page and select the libraries you want.

For example if I ignore Bootstrap (just for this demo), and if I choose plain DataTables with jQuery and buttons, I get the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css"/>
 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.5/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
```

Using these with your code allows your buttons to be displayed.

You can add back in the extra libraries you also want - for exaple, for `moment.js`. You can adjust for Bootstrap, also, as needed.